# OnUploadedComplete function of AsyncFileUpload is never hit in detailsview

Tags: vb.net, updatepanel, detailsview, asyncfileupload

I have an AsyncFileUpload control in a detailsview. I can browse to select a file to upload. When I start the upload the `OnClientUploadComplete` function `uploadRoomThumbComplete` method is executed, but the function in `OnUploadedComplete` is never hit.

Why?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

    <asp:DetailsView AutoGenerateRows="False" DefaultMode="Edit" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="odsDetails" ID="dvOfferDetails" runat="server">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Glossary,image%>">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:literal ID="ltImage" runat="server" /> 
                <p id="RoomContainer">
                </p>
                <asp:literal ID="ltDeleteRoomThumb" runat="server" />
                <cc1:AsyncFileUpload CssClass="imageUploaderField" ID="afuRoomThumb" Width="150" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" OnUploadedComplete="afuRoomThumb_UploadedComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadRoomThumbComplete" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>            
    </Fields>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>



Protected Sub afuRoomThumb_UploadedComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)
    '---> this codeblock is NEVER hit....why?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1477331.aspx?AsyncFileUpload+inside+a+GridView+inside+an+UpdatePanel

In short: place another AsyncFileUpload control on the page and set the style's display:none.

It seems that the AsyncFileUpload is designed to be used only once on a page, and when you put it on your master page, any afu inside an updatepanel will work.